# PHP date function giving a random number

Tags: php

Hello i'm making a php script to send an email on a client's birthday, basicly i'm looping through every client's birthdates and checking with today's date and if they match, an email is sent. Although the date function is giving a random number instead of today's date, the number is: 1505451600.

Maybe i'm doing something wrong in the code? Does anyone know a way to fix this?

```
$get_birthday = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT email, dt_nascimento FROM clientes");
if ($get_birthday->execute()) {
    while ($array_birthday = $get_birthday->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $birthdate = date('m d', strtotime($array_birthday['dt_nascimento']));
        // echo "</br> data:".$array_birthday['dt_nascimento'];
        // echo "</br>".$birthdate;
        $now = date("m/d");
        $now = strtotime($now);
        // echo "</br>now: ".$now;
        $email = $array_birthday['email'];
        if ($now == $birthdate) {
            include"PHPMailer/email_birthday.php";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1505451600 Is equivalent to: 09/15/2017 @ 5:00am (UTC)

Comment: Then why does it give that number instead of only the day and month?

Comment: `strtotime` gives you timestamp of a passed date. What do you expect?

Comment: Why just don't do an SQL query that gives you the clients born on this day and removes all the PHP logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 changes you need to make for your code to work:

(1) Remove this line:

```
$now = strtotime($now);
```

Reason: You don't want a timestamp. You want a formatted date.

(2) Change "m d" on this line:

```
$birthdate = date('m d', strtotime($array_birthday['dt_nascimento']));
```

to "m/d" like so:

```
$birthdate = date('m/d', strtotime($array_birthday['dt_nascimento']));
```

Reason: you need to format `$birthdate` and `$now` the same way to make the comparison work.

Answer (score 1):

I remove the $now conversion to timestamp and change the $birthdate format to the same as $now.
This is the working code :

```
$get_birthday = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT email, dt_nascimento FROM clientes");
if ($get_birthday->execute()) {
    while ($array_birthday = $get_birthday->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $birthdate = date('m d', strtotime($array_birthday['dt_nascimento']));
        // echo "</br> data:".$array_birthday['dt_nascimento'];
        // echo "</br>".$birthdate;
        $now = date("m d");
        // echo "</br>now: ".$now;
        $email = $array_birthday['email'];
        if ($now == $birthdate) {
            include"PHPMailer/email_birthday.php";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Although you fix is correct, comparing `"m/d"`-format with `'m d'`-format simply will __never__ be true.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it gives you a number is how computers measure time is the number of seconds since 1/1/1970 00:00 (UTC (Universal Time)).

Answer (score 0):

`1505451600` Is equivalent to: `09/15/2017 @ 5:00am (UTC)`

this happens because:

`date("m/d")` returns `9/15` (today month/day)

then [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) tries to convert this string into unix timestamp, as soon as year is not in string, current year (2017) is assumed

as soon as time part is not there, midnight in your timezone is assumed (5am utc)

this is why final time is 1505451600